# Asp.net Core 2.1 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, .net-core, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-2.1

I tried some routing in asp.net core 2.1 and facing a issue with routing...

Startup.cs -> Configure Method

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default", 
                template: "{Controller=Demo}/{Action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

DemoController.cs

```
[Route("demo")]
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("index")]
    [Route("MyDemoPage")]
    [Route("~/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("demo2/{id}")]
    [Route("cj/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Demo2(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return View("Demo2");
    }

    [Route("demo3/{id1}/{id2}")]
    [Route("cc/{id1}/{id2}")]
    public IActionResult Demo3(int id1,string id2)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id1;
        ViewBag.id2 = id2;
        return View("Demo3");
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml Page

```
@*[Route("demo2/{id}")]*@
<br />
<a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="demo2" asp-route-id="123">Demo2</a>
@*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/cj/123">Demo2</a>*@ Link 1
<br />
@*[Route("cj/{id}")]*@
<br />
<a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="cj" asp-route-id="07">Demo2 via route CJ</a>
@*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/cj/07">Demo2 via route CJ</a>*@ Link 2

<br />
@*[Route("demo3/{id1}/{id2}")]*@
<br />
<a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="demo3" asp-route-id1="123" asp-route-id2="P001">Demo3</a>
@*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/cc/123/P001">Demo3</a>*@ Link 3
<br />
@*[Route("cc/{id1}/{id2}")]*@
<br />
<a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="cc" asp-route-id1="123" asp-route-id2="abc">Demo via CC</a>
@*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/cc?id1=123&id2=abc">Demo via CC</a>*@ Link 4
```

Demo2.cshtml

```
 @*[Route("index")]*@
    <br />
    <a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="index">Index Page</a>
    @*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/MyDemoPage">Index Page</a>*@ Link 5
    <br />
    @*[Route("MyDemoPage")]*@
    <br />
    <a asp-controller="demo" asp-action="MyDemoPage">Index Page via MyDemoPage 
    Route</a>
    @*Above Tag renders :> <a href="/demo/MyDemoPage">Index Page via MyDemoPage 
    Route</a>*@ Link 6
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/chandrahasJ/AspNetCorePratice/tree/master/Project5_RouteWithParameter)

I am confuse why did Link 4 & Link 3 are different in index.cshtml and 
Link 5 & Link 6 rendered same href
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reason that different result for **Link 5 & Link 6**, they are generated by different rules.

For URL generation, `RouteCollection` call [GetVirtualPath](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/9e114b547dffc838a3713a80a059249f8d25842c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteCollection.cs#L117) to use `IRouter` to generate the url. There are two default irouter, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler`.

For `asp-action="index"`, it is handled by `AttributeRoute` and [GetMatches](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/6f4c10a664bbb155e5085e822f126feef1d33eb4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Internal/LinkGenerationDecisionTree.cs#L27) will order the `MyDemoPage` before `index`. You could check [OutboundMatchResultComparer](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/6f4c10a664bbb155e5085e822f126feef1d33eb4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Internal/LinkGenerationDecisionTree.cs#L138)  to check compare logic. If you change `[Route("MyDemoPage")]` to `[Route("myDemoPage")]`, it will generate **/demo/index**.

For `asp-action="MyDemoPage"`, `GetMatches` return zero count for `IList<OutboundMatchResult>`. Then, it goes to `MvcRouteHandler`, and call `RouteBase`. [_binder.BindValues(values.AcceptedValues);](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/3a022107dcba43fb6441a5fad741537f17a5fd17/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteBase.cs#L152) will generate **/demo/MyDemoPage**.

The different result for `GetMatches` is controlled by whether value for `asp-action` exist in the Controller Action. For your scenario, `Index` is exist, but `MyDemoPage` not, there is no corresponding method for `MyDemoPage`.

**Update**

**One more time, the key different result is caused by whether the
 `action` is real exist in the Controller method.**

For `asp-action="cc"`, there is no `cc` action in `DemoController`, it goes with `Controller MVC Binder`, and format as `/demo/cc?id1=123&id2=abc`.

For `asp-action="demo3"`, there is action called `demo3`, it is generated by `Router Attribute Binder`, and will generate `_template = "demo/cc/{id1}/{id2}"` and `_template = "demo/demo3/{id1}/{id2}"` in order. For the order, it will return `/demo/cc/123/P001`.

Comment: #Tao Zhuo - Thanks for the time. For Link 5 & Link 6 They are both using same attributes asp-route-id1 & asp-route-id2 only action value is different i.e. "cc" & "demo3" but one is creating link with old style query string  i.e. cc?id1=123&id2=abc & one is creating cc/123/P001

Comment: #Tao Zhuo - What is Different